# Pandas "countif" based on column value and multiindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, count

I have a DataFrame that looks like:
[image]

Where I have `YEAR` and `RACEETHN` as a `multiindex`. I want to to count the number of "1" values (note, the data are not only 0 and 1 so I cannot do a sum) for each `YEAR` and `RACEETHN` combination for each column variable.

I am able to count where value = 1 for each column by doing this:

```
(df_3.ACSUPPSV == 1).sum()
(df_3.PSEDSUPPSV == 1).sum()
```

I want to do this with `groupby`, but am unable to get it to work. I've tried the following code to test if I could do it on a single column `'ACSUPPSV'` and it did no work:

```
df.groupby(['YEAR', 'RACEETHN']).loc[df.ACSUPPSV == 1, 'ACSUPPSV'].count()
```

I exported the data to excel and was able to calculate this with a quick "`COUNTIF`" formula, but I know there must be a way to do this in pandas - the results from excel look like:

[image]

Would appreciate if someone had a better way to do this than export to Excel! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with custom function for count `1` only:

```
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'ACSUPPSV':[1,1,1,1,0,1],
                   'PSEDSUPPSV':[1,1,0,1,0,0],
                   'BUDGETSV':[1,0,1,1,1,0],
                   'YEAR':[2000,2000,2001,2000,2000,2000],
                   'RACEETHN':list('aaabbb')}).set_index(['YEAR','RACEETHN'])

print (df_3)

               ACSUPPSV  BUDGETSV  PSEDSUPPSV
YEAR RACEETHN                                
2000 a                1         1           1
     a                1         0           1
2001 a                1         1           0
2000 b                1         1           1
     b                0         1           0
     b                1         0           0

df2 = df_3.groupby(['YEAR', 'RACEETHN']).agg(lambda x: (x == 1).sum())
print (df2)
               ACSUPPSV  BUDGETSV  PSEDSUPPSV
YEAR RACEETHN                                
2000 a                2         1           2
     b                2         2           1
2001 a                1         1           0
```

Old answer:

```
df_3[((df_3.ACSUPPSV == 1) & (df_3.PSEDSUPPSV == 1))].groupby(['YEAR', 'RACEETHN']).size()

df_3.query('ACSUPPSV == 1 & PSEDSUPPSV == 1').groupby(['YEAR', 'RACEETHN']).size()
```

More general:

```
cols = ['ACSUPPSV','PSEDSUPPSV']
df_3[(df_3[cols] == 1).all(axis=1)].groupby(['YEAR', 'RACEETHN']).size()
```

For all columns:

```
df_3[(df_3 == 1).all(axis=1)].groupby(['YEAR', 'RACEETHN']).size()
```

EDIT:

Or maybe need:

```
df_3.groupby(['YEAR', 'RACEETHN']).agg(lambda x: (x == 1).sum())
```

Comment: missing a df :-)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can quickly do this calculation for each column name separately without having to write each and every one out? So 'ACSUPPSV' 'PSEDSUPPSV' 'BUDGETSV' and so on...

Comment: One more question - what if I wanted to meet two conditions e.g: df_3.groupby(['YEAR', 'RACEETHN']).agg(lambda x: (x == 1 or x == 0).sum()). This obviously doesn't work but what if I want the condition to be either 1 or 0?

Comment: Use `((x == 1) | (x == 0)).sum()`,but better is for multiple or use `(x.isin([0,1]) ).sum()`

Comment: Just realized my error - thanks for the really quick replies! I really appreciate it :)